# What effects could long-term nursing have on a cat?

Tags: cats, feeding, multi-pet-families

I have a cat thats 9 months old. The mother ended up getting pregnant again shortly after (fixed now, so no more worries), which lead to one of my cats to continue nursing after being introduced to regular dry cat food. Only one of the two kittens from that litter chose to continue nursing AND eat regular kitten food.

After the birth, we litter trained the kittens and had to give them to some family friends (sadly, I can't have an army of cats at my house). After the fact, we noticed that one of the kittens from the litter before is STILL nursing on her mother.

Other than not being as big as her brother (same age, but male. I'm guessing it's a gender thing), she seems perfectly fine.

How can nursing affect a 9 month old cat who also eats regular cat food? How could it affect a cat that *doesn't* eat regular cat food, and chooses to only nurse?